# When do "old" OAuth 1.0 access tokens become invalid?

Tags: api, rest, oauth

Working with an external service API that uses OAuth 1.0 for access to protected resources.

I issued a successful API call to this external service signing the API call using the access token secret for my user that was previously acquired during the OAuth 1.0 authorization process.

Did some refactoring, and just as a sanity check, ran through the OAuth 1.0 authorization process again with the same user, which issued a new access token and secret.

Did some more refactoring, and to test that refactoring, re-ran the API call to access protected resources.  However, I forgot to change the (temporarily hardcoded) access token/secret for my user.  The access token/secret was still the previous values before successfully going through the authorization process a second time.  I would have expected my API call to fail since the user had been issued a new access token/secret and I was using the previous access token/secret.  I would have expected it to fail because one would, maybe incorrectly, assume that getting a new access token for the same user and consumer would invalidate any previously issued access tokens.

This did not happen.

I was able to make the same API call successfully using either the previous access token/secret or the newly acquired access token/secret.

Is this correct behavior?  If so, do "old" access tokens ever get invalidated?

Comment: I don’t see anything about access token expiry mentioned in RFC 5849 (besides the mere fact that they _can_ expire) – so I’d assume that it is up to the implementer whether/when access tokens expire.

Comment: So they don't get revoked when a new access token is provided?  Some Googling about this brought up OAuth 2.0 and that not revoking an old token when a new one is granted is a valid scenario, but also seems to be somewhat related to scopes, which I don't believe are present in OAuth 1.0.  (Also, OAuth 2.0 is a completely different protocol from 1.0).